# understanding house sister

Tags: british-english, slang, understanding

what "esteemed house sister" means in the sentence?

Alice. In my short time as your head of dorm. I and Mia, your esteemed house sister.

The passage's from That Face (Play)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google books "That Face"](https://books.google.com/books?id=7F2lDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT13&lpg=PT13&dq=Alice.%20In%20my%20short%20time%20as%20your%20head%20of%20dorm.%20I%20and%20Mia,%20your%20esteemed%20house%20sister.&source=bl&ots=HlFUf8UEgj&sig=ACfU3U24XYn9KX9KUb1_UTsrK5Yr4vkTZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOks2C_5LrAhUQPq0KHefZCaQQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Alice.%20In%20my%20short%20time%20as%20your%20head%20of%20dorm.%20I%20and%20Mia%2C%20your%20esteemed%20house%20sister.&f=false)

The play's first scene depicts some girls who share a dormitory and who have one of their number tied to a chair, after having poisoned her with a tranquilizer. They are taking her to task for wearing a religious symbol.

The words "house sister" are used here to refer to someone who lives in a dormitory for females. Dormitories are shared living spaces for college students that are sometimes called "houses", and where the residents may sometimes call each other "sisters" or "brothers", because, living in a dormitory, they are in a kind of club.

[Wikipedia "dormitory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormitory)

The word "esteemed" usually means "admired and respected". The use here is mocking. The entire phrase, "esteemed house sister". which occurs earlier in the scene as well, has a mock formality and is not respectful.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer and deleted my less than insightful comment in the light of it.